# How to use long key presses in python and raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pynput

I have a raspberry pi with a few motors. I have tried pynput but when I hold a button it continuously activates the function. I want to make it activate a function until I let go of the button. How would I go about doing that?

This is the janky code I have right now.

```py
def show(key):
    if key == Key.delete: 
        return False
    elif key == Key.up:
        print("forward")
        left_turn(0.1)
    elif key == Key.right:
        print("right")
        forward(0.1)
    elif key == Key.left:
        print("left")
        reverse(0.1)
    elif key == Key.down:
        print("reverse")
        right_turn(0.1) 
  
# Collect all event until released
with Listener(on_press = show) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "activate a function until I let go"? What should it do in that function during that time?

Comment: I dont think that matters. I only want the function to happen continuously until I let go of the button. Something like a loop that triggers a function when and only when I am pressing the button. Until I let go it does the function.

Comment: But what does it mean for a function to "happen continuously"? Should it be called repeatedly? Words really matter when you are trying to specify the behaviour of a system.